# Why are .out files hexadecimal instead of binary

Tags: c++, linux

From my knowledge, when you compile a file, say a .cpp file, it should transform it to a binary file in order for the machine to understand it. However, after compiling the file and obtaining the .out file, I see that inside it is a hexadecimal code instead of a binary. Can please somebody explain to me what I'm missing?

Comment: Possibly because the tool you are using to examine the file displays it in hex?

Comment: *How* do you see that? Also what makes you think that binary and hexadecimal are different? They're just numeral systems

Comment: I'm using sublime text. Yes, I know it's just another numeric system, but I don't think that the CPU can transform it by itself to binary in order to run the program.

Comment: *What* makes you think the CPU needs to transform anything? Just because one of your programs displays the executable machine code as hexadecimal values does not mean it's in a format the CPU doesn't understand - it's still numbers after all and *everything* on a PC boils down to binary numbers

Comment: None of this makes any sense at all. What does it mean to "be" binary, or hexadecimal? The file contains bytes, which have values. Values "are" not binary or hexadecimal. Is the value of the numbers of fingers on your hand binary or hexadecimal? What about the number of eyes?

Comment: FYI: When I inspect an a.out file using the 'default' mode "Text View Fill", the first few letters displayed are not hex, nor are they text.  For instance, emacs shows (between quotes) "^?ELF^B^A^A6@" and many more.   From wiki "In computing, the Executable and Linkable Format (ELF, formerly named Extensible Linking Format), is a common standard file format for executable files, object code, shared libraries, and core dumps."  In emacs, it is trivial to show hex contents (when I can remember the incantation).  I suspect that Sublime is capable of other modes too.

Comment: Numbers are numbers. When you convert a numeric value to text you decide how to display it: decimal, binary, octal, hexadecimal, whatever. The text representation that you select has no connection to the data that it's being used to display.

Comment: "I see inside it is a ..."  No.  You see a presentation created by the editor.

Answer (score 0):

Sublime Text is automatically detecting the file as a binary image and showing you the file with the hexadecimal viewer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you might like a 'positive' answer, as in 'How do I inspect an object file which is part of my build? or the result of my build?'

IMHO, the comments (including my own) are poorly stating that you have used an editor, which is, in some ways, the wrong tool, to inspect a binary executable or .o file.

Perhaps a more 'correct' tool is objdump.  It, however, has a discouraging number of options.  Still, you should try it.

If, on the other hand, you want to see a real hex dump, linux has a tool called hexdump.  Something to compare to what your editor produces?

---

From wikipedia:

"objdump is a program for displaying various information about object files. For instance, it can be used as a disassembler to view an executable in assembly form. It is part of the GNU Binutils for fine-grained control over executables and other binary data."

Example:  (of the beginning of a linkable .o file)

> objdump -x -T eng_format.o

```
 eng_format.o:     file format elf64-x86-64
 eng_format.o
 architecture: i386:x86-64, flags 0x00000011:
 HAS_RELOC, HAS_SYMS
 start address 0x0000000000000000
 
 Sections:
 Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
   0 .group        00000008  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000040  2**2
                   CONTENTS, READONLY, EXCLUDE, GROUP, LINK_ONCE_DISCARD
   1 .group        00000008  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000048  2**2
                   CONTENTS, READONLY, EXCLUDE, GROUP, LINK_ONCE_DISCARD
   2 .group        00000008  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000050  2**2
                   CONTENTS, READONLY, EXCLUDE, GROUP, LINK_ONCE_DISCARD
   3 .group        00000008  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000058  2**2
                   CONTENTS, READONLY, EXCLUDE, GROUP, LINK_ONCE_DISCARD
   4 .group        00000008  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000060  2**2
                   CONTENTS, READONLY, EXCLUDE, GROUP, LINK_ONCE_DISCARD
   5 .group        00000008  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000068  2**2
                   CONTENTS, READONLY, EXCLUDE, GROUP, LINK_ONCE_DISCARD
   6 .group        00000008  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000070  2**2
                   CONTENTS, READONLY, EXCLUDE, GROUP, LINK_ONCE_DISCARD
   7 .group        00000008  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000078  2**2
                   CONTENTS, READONLY, EXCLUDE, GROUP, LINK_ONCE_DISCARD
   8 .group        00000008  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000080  2**2
                   CONTENTS, READONLY, EXCLUDE, GROUP, LINK_ONCE_DISCARD
   9 .group        00000008  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000088  2**2
                   CONTENTS, READONLY, EXCLUDE, GROUP, LINK_ONCE_DISCARD
  10 .group        00000008  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000090  2**2
                   CONTENTS, READONLY, EXCLUDE, GROUP, LINK_ONCE_DISCARD
  11 .text         00000d85  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000098  2**0
                   CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, CODE
  12 .data         00000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000e1d  2**0
                   CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  13 .bss          00000002  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000e1d  2**0
                   ALLOC
  14 .rodata       000001f8  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00000e20  2**5
                   CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, DATA
  15 .text._ZStanSt13_Ios_FmtflagsS_ 00000014  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00001018  2**0
                   CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  16 .text._ZStorSt13_Ios_FmtflagsS_ 00000014  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000102c  2**0
                   CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  17 .text._ZStcoSt13_Ios_Fmtflags 0000000e  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00001040  2**0
                   CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  18 .text._ZStoRRSt13_Ios_FmtflagsS_ 0000002f  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000104e  2**0
                   CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, CODE
  19 .text._ZStaNRSt13_Ios_FmtflagsS_ 0000002f  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000107d  2**0
                   CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, CODE
  20 .text._ZNSt8ios_base4setfESt13_Ios_FmtflagsS0_ 00000062  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  000010ac  2**1
                   CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, CODE
  21 .text._ZSt5fixedRSt8ios_base 00000028  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000110e  2**0
                   CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, CODE
  22 .text._ZSt12setprecisioni 0000000c  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00001136  2**0
                   CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  23 .text._ZSt10fpclassifyd 0000006b  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00001142  2**0
                   CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, CODE
  24 .gcc_except_table 000000b9  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  000011ad  2**0
                   CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  25
 .text._ZSt4moveIRNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEONSt16remove_referenceIT_E4typeEOS8_
 0000000e  0000000000000000  000000000000000     0  00001266  2**0
                   CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  26 .text._ZStplIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIT_T0_T1_EEOS8_PKS5_ 00000047  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00001274  2**0
                   CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, CODE
  27 .debug_info   00007f49  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  000012bb  2**0
                   CONTENTS, RELOC, READONLY, DEBUGGING
  28 .debug_abbrev 00000765  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00009204  2**0
                   CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
  29 .debug_aranges 000000e0  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00009969  2**0
                   CONTENTS, RELOC, READONLY, DEBUGGING
  30 .debug_ranges 00000130  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00009a49  2**0
                   CONTENTS, RELOC, READONLY, DEBUGGING
  31 .debug_line   00000742  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00009b79  2**0
                   CONTENTS, RELOC, READONLY, DEBUGGING
  32 .debug_str    0000b297  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000a2bb  2**0
                   CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
  33 .comment      00000034  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00015552  2**0
                   CONTENTS, READONLY
  34 .note.GNU-stack 00000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00015586  2**0
                   CONTENTS, READONLY
  35 .eh_frame     00000388  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00015588  2**3
                   CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, DATA
 objdump: eng_format.o: not a dynamic object
 SYMBOL TABLE:
 0000000000000000 l    df *ABS* 0000000000000000 eng_format.cpp
 0000000000000000 l    d  .text 0000000000000000 .text
 0000000000000000 l    d  .data 0000000000000000 .data
 0000000000000000 l    d  .bss  0000000000000000 .bss
 0000000000000000 l    d  .rodata   0000000000000000 .rodata
 0000000000000000 l     O .rodata   0000000000000001 _ZStL19piecewise_construct
 0000000000000001 l     O .rodata   0000000000000001 _ZL13eng_increment
 0000000000000002 l     O .rodata   0000000000000001 _ZL13eng_decrement
 0000000000000000 l    d  .text._ZStanSt13_Ios_FmtflagsS_   0000000000000000 .text._ZStanSt13_Ios_FmtflagsS_
 0000000000000000 l    d  .text._ZStorSt13_Ios_FmtflagsS_   0000000000000000 .text._ZStorSt13_Ios_FmtflagsS_
 0000000000000000 l    d  .text._ZStcoSt13_Ios_Fmtflags 0000000000000000 .text._ZStcoSt13_Ios_Fmtflags
 0000000000000000 l    d  .text._ZStoRRSt13_Ios_FmtflagsS_  0000000000000000 .text._ZStoRRSt13_Ios_FmtflagsS_
 0000000000000000 l    d  .text._ZStaNRSt13_Ios_FmtflagsS_  0000000000000000 .text._ZStaNRSt13_Ios_FmtflagsS_
 0000000000000000 l    d  .text._ZNSt8ios_base4setfESt13_Ios_FmtflagsS0_    0000000000000000 .text._ZNSt8ios_base4setfESt13_Ios_FmtflagsS0_
 0000000000000000 l    d  .text._ZSt5fixedRSt8ios_base  0000000000000000 .text._ZSt5fixedRSt8ios_base
 0000000000000003 l     O .rodata   0000000000000001 _ZStL13allocator_arg
 0000000000000004 l     O .rodata   0000000000000001 _ZStL6ignore
 0000000000000000 l    d  .text._ZSt12setprecisioni 0000000000000000 .text._ZSt12setprecisioni
 0000000000000000 l    d  .text._ZSt10fpclassifyd   0000000000000000 .text._ZSt10fpclassifyd
 0000000000000080 l     O .rodata   0000000000000120 _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_1L8prefixesE
```

... total of 2300 lines.  You really "gotta wanna" to search through this.

---

Example: (of 1st 100 lines of elf executable)

objdump -x -T FMssb_ut

```
 FMssb_ut:     file format elf64-x86-64
 FMssb_ut
 architecture: i386:x86-64, flags 0x00000112:
 EXEC_P, HAS_SYMS, D_PAGED
 start address 0x0000000000402b10
 
 Program Header:
     PHDR off    0x0000000000000040 vaddr 0x0000000000400040 paddr 0x0000000000400040 align 2**3
          filesz 0x00000000000001f8 memsz 0x00000000000001f8 flags r-x
   INTERP off    0x0000000000000238 vaddr 0x0000000000400238 paddr 0x0000000000400238 align 2**0
          filesz 0x000000000000001c memsz 0x000000000000001c flags r--
     LOAD off    0x0000000000000000 vaddr 0x0000000000400000 paddr 0x0000000000400000 align 2**21
          filesz 0x00000000000109a8 memsz 0x00000000000109a8 flags r-x
     LOAD off    0x0000000000010db0 vaddr 0x0000000000610db0 paddr 0x0000000000610db0 align 2**21
          filesz 0x00000000000004e8 memsz 0x0000000000000928 flags rw-
  DYNAMIC off    0x0000000000010dd8 vaddr 0x0000000000610dd8 paddr 0x0000000000610dd8 align 2**3
          filesz 0x0000000000000220 memsz 0x0000000000000220 flags rw-
     NOTE off    0x0000000000000254 vaddr 0x0000000000400254 paddr 0x0000000000400254 align 2**2
          filesz 0x0000000000000044 memsz 0x0000000000000044 flags r--
 EH_FRAME off    0x000000000000ee48 vaddr 0x000000000040ee48 paddr 0x000000000040ee48 align 2**2
          filesz 0x000000000000022c memsz 0x000000000000022c flags r--
    STACK off    0x0000000000000000 vaddr 0x0000000000000000 paddr 0x0000000000000000 align 2**4
          filesz 0x0000000000000000 memsz 0x0000000000000000 flags rw-
    RELRO off    0x0000000000010db0 vaddr 0x0000000000610db0 paddr 0x0000000000610db0 align 2**0
          filesz 0x0000000000000250 memsz 0x0000000000000250 flags r--
 
 Dynamic Section:
   NEEDED               librt.so.1
   NEEDED               libstdc++.so.6
   NEEDED               libm.so.6
   NEEDED               libgcc_s.so.1
   NEEDED               libpthread.so.0
   NEEDED               libc.so.6
   INIT                 0x0000000000402358
   FINI                 0x000000000040e604
   INIT_ARRAY           0x0000000000610db0
   INIT_ARRAYSZ         0x0000000000000018
   FINI_ARRAY           0x0000000000610dc8
   FINI_ARRAYSZ         0x0000000000000008
   GNU_HASH             0x0000000000400298
   STRTAB               0x0000000000400bd0
   SYMTAB               0x0000000000400300
   STRSZ                0x0000000000000d54
   SYMENT               0x0000000000000018
   DEBUG                0x0000000000000000
   PLTGOT               0x0000000000611000
   PLTRELSZ             0x0000000000000750
   PLTREL               0x0000000000000007
   JMPREL               0x0000000000401c08
   RELA                 0x0000000000401b30
   RELASZ               0x00000000000000d8
   RELAENT              0x0000000000000018
   VERNEED              0x00000000004019e0
   VERNEEDNUM           0x0000000000000006
   VERSYM               0x0000000000401924
 
 Version References:
   required from librt.so.1:
     0x09691a75 0x00 15 GLIBC_2.2.5
   required from libgcc_s.so.1:
     0x0b792650 0x00 14 GCC_3.0
   required from libc.so.6:
     0x06969194 0x00 16 GLIBC_2.14
     0x0d696914 0x00 12 GLIBC_2.4
     0x09691a75 0x00 07 GLIBC_2.2.5
   required from libpthread.so.0:
     0x09691a75 0x00 05 GLIBC_2.2.5
   required from libstdc++.so.6:
     0x056bafd3 0x00 13 CXXABI_1.3
     0x02297f89 0x00 11 GLIBCXX_3.4.9
     0x0297f868 0x00 10 GLIBCXX_3.4.18
     0x0bafd179 0x00 09 CXXABI_1.3.9
     0x0297f861 0x00 08 GLIBCXX_3.4.11
     0x0297f870 0x00 06 GLIBCXX_3.4.20
     0x08922974 0x00 04 GLIBCXX_3.4
     0x0297f871 0x00 03 GLIBCXX_3.4.21
   required from libm.so.6:
     0x09691a75 0x00 02 GLIBC_2.2.5
 
 Sections:
 Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
   0 .interp       0000001c  0000000000400238  0000000000400238  00000238  2**0
                   CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
   1 .note.ABI-tag 00000020  0000000000400254  0000000000400254  00000254  2**2
                   CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
   2 .note.gnu.build-id 00000024  0000000000400274  0000000000400274  00000274  2**2
                   CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
   3 .gnu.hash     00000064  0000000000400298  0000000000400298  00000298  2**3
                   CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
   4 .dynsym       000008d0  0000000000400300  0000000000400300  00000300  2**3
                   CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
   5 .dynstr       00000d54  0000000000400bd0  0000000000400bd0  00000bd0  2**0
                   CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
   6 .gnu.version  000000bc  0000000000401924  0000000000401924  00001924  2**1
                   CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
   7 .gnu.version_r 00000150  00000000004019e0  00000000004019e0  000019e0  2**3
                   CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
```

...1st 100 lines of 500

---

An example of hexdump:

```
 hexdump FMssb_ut
 0000000 457f 464c 0102 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000
 0000010 0002 003e 0001 0000 2b10 0040 0000 0000
 0000020 0040 0000 0000 0000 3bb0 000c 0000 0000
 0000030 0000 0000 0040 0038 0009 0040 0026 0023
 0000040 0006 0000 0005 0000 0040 0000 0000 0000
 0000050 0040 0040 0000 0000 0040 0040 0000 0000
 0000060 01f8 0000 0000 0000 01f8 0000 0000 0000
 0000070 0008 0000 0000 0000 0003 0000 0004 0000
 0000080 0238 0000 0000 0000 0238 0040 0000 0000
 0000090 0238 0040 0000 0000 001c 0000 0000 0000
 00000a0 001c 0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000
 00000b0 0001 0000 0005 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
 00000c0 0000 0040 0000 0000 0000 0040 0000 0000
 00000d0 09a8 0001 0000 0000 09a8 0001 0000 0000
 00000e0 0000 0020 0000 0000 0001 0000 0006 0000
 00000f0 0db0 0001 0000 0000 0db0 0061 0000 0000
 0000100 0db0 0061 0000 0000 04e8 0000 0000 0000
 0000110 0928 0000 0000 0000 0000 0020 0000 0000
 0000120 0002 0000 0006 0000 0dd8 0001 0000 0000
 0000130 0dd8 0061 0000 0000 0dd8 0061 0000 0000
 0000140 0220 0000 0000 0000 0220 0000 0000 0000
 0000150 0008 0000 0000 0000 0004 0000 0004 0000
 0000160 0254 0000 0000 0000 0254 0040 0000 0000
 0000170 0254 0040 0000 0000 0044 0000 0000 0000
 0000180 0044 0000 0000 0000 0004 0000 0000 0000
 0000190 e550 6474 0004 0000 ee48 0000 0000 0000
 00001a0 ee48 0040 0000 0000 ee48 0040 0000 0000
 00001b0 022c 0000 0000 0000 022c 0000 0000 0000
 00001c0 0004 0000 0000 0000 e551 6474 0006 0000
 00001d0 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
 *
 00001f0 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010 0000 0000 0000
 0000200 e552 6474 0004 0000 0db0 0001 0000 0000
 0000210 0db0 0061 0000 0000 0db0 0061 0000 0000
 0000220 0250 0000 0000 0000 0250 0000 0000 0000
 0000230 0001 0000 0000 0000 6c2f 6269 3436 6c2f
 0000240 2d64 696c 756e 2d78 3878 2d36 3436 732e
 0000250 2e6f 0032 0004 0000 0010 0000 0001 0000
 0000260 4e47 0055 0000 0000 0002 0000 0006 0000
 0000270 0020 0000 0004 0000 0014 0000 0003 0000
 0000280 4e47 0055 6242 90f3 5153 ecd4 c394 9df4
 0000290 5ffe e03c cd6c 546e 0003 0000 0050 0000
 00002a0 0002 0000 0007 0000 2c01 4410 a124 0201
 00002b0 1400 0024 0d00 298c 0050 0000 0052 0000
 00002c0 0055 0000 6afc 2380 6d25 430c bc72 3a06
 00002d0 956a 2db4 f12d 5e5f 1bcc feea 200c feea
 00002e0 4528 4cd5 178a feea 9814 430c 1c9e b870
 ....
```

...The beginning of a 50,000 line text file.

---

Note: some editor's might have more info in their mode for binary files.  In emacs, I once connected objdump to a function key, and emacs could show me the objdump in another buffer.

On the other hand, I have seldom investigated executable contents.  A decade or so ago, the 'embedded-world' tool suite still required the developer to create a link map as input, so investigating this way was useful.  I've not done this kind of investigation in the last decade, probably because the new embedded systems have a lot more dram.

There are other tools (beyond objdump).  Google can help find them.